# How to manage build.gradle files on microservices?

Tags: spring-boot

I would be interested to know how others manage build.gradle files of a large number of spring boot/cloud microservices. e.g when you have to update the version of a single lib (because of a security issue) do you update each microservice manually or does a management tool exists? Or do you share common settings in parent config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually create a common gradle file which is linked in each of the services. Any security issues for any of the jars we find will be updated in the main build gradle and then we do a refresh of all our services so that the changes are applied.

Comment: what a coincidence. I am currently working on a similar solution. using gradle version catalog and renovate to automate version update

Comment: haha nice. let me know how it goes